# Composer dump-autoload, issue

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, helper, laravel-artisan

While Working on a project using Laravel 4 to be precise, I decided that i wanted to make my own helper file to house my custom functions.. one of which is this below...

```
function pr($ar=array(), $bool=false){

   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($ar);
   echo '</pre>';

   if($bool){
      exit;
   }

}
```

in my composer.json file, just after the autoload: classmap , i added myne, autoload:files -arrar and included my custom file, app/helpers as illustrated below..

```
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ],

        "others":[
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
```

and i switched to my terminal window and ran the following commands

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

but i still got errors that my pr() function was undefined... then i tried the artisan alternative... [-o ] to optimize the files

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

but still it refused to work... and then i changed the array name from

```
"others":[
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
```

to

```
"files":[
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
```

then i got the desired response, my code could now see the custom function i wrote, please i'd like to know if there is a pattern i was supposed to follow or otherwise, in my case, i mistook " files ", for " others " and i got errors, but incase, what did i miss here, all i see is just a name-string value for the array representation....

Comment: should incase someone is wondering, i prefer my pr() function to the native dd() - die dump function... it suits me well.. i'm just being me, #period

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how composer works. In `autoload` section you need to use `files` when you want to load some files. In my Laravel 5 project I have for example:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "verify\\": "verify/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/functions.php"
    ]
},
```

If you look at [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files) you will see that you need to use `files` to load any extra files by autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload)

> Currently PSR-0 autoloading, PSR-4 autoloading, classmap generation
>   and files includes are supported. PSR-4 is the recommended way though
>   since it offers greater ease of use (no need to regenerate the
>   autoloader when you add classes).

So the reason that `"others"` did not work was because it is not supported by composer. `"others"` is simply meaningless, while `"files"` actually have a [specific autoloading mechanism](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files).